# Is there an elegant way to use percentages in jQuery.animate( )?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have spent a significant amount of time looking for a solution to use percentages in .animate() but I can't find one.

Normally, I would be fine with using pixels but I want to animate images that scale responsively so unless I position them with percentages, they will not hold they position as the screen shrinks or grows.

This is what I have been using so far but it changes the elements percentages to pixels and is off by a few.

```
// calculate the percentage to px for jQuery .animate()
var yPos = $this.data('offsetY');  // original percentage value for top:
yPos = ($this.width() * (yPos / 100));
$this.animate({ "top": yPos }, 800);
```

Unfortunately this sets the elements position as pixels so if the user shrinks the screen or tilts their device the images positions will not scale correctly like it would with the percentage value.

Are there any elegant solutions to remedy this?

Thanks.

Comment: `yPos = (parseInt($this.css('width'),10) * (yPos / 100));`

Comment: @adeneo what difference compare to using: `$this.width()` ?

Comment: The root of my problem is that I want to get percentages into my elements when I move them via animation. Otherwise, if the user shrinks or grows the screen, the positions will be off since they are now pixels.

Comment: @A.Wolff - ooops, my thinking was way of, they are of course the same, and parseInt on the style actually makes them exactly equal. To get the percentage one would have to calculate it based on the parent elements dimensions etc.

Comment: Ok, so what I did was use some 3rd grade algebra to convert back to percentage and then I injected them back into to element via .css() in a callback function. It works but it makes the transitions somewhat jarring. I am incorporating the animations into a parallax scrolling. I wonder if that is whats causing the stutter.